# How do I work out the time complexity of the following binary tree functions?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I have just started to learn about time complexity and I'm really struggling to grasp the concept, how would I go about working out the time complexity of the following function? Is this one O(n^2) because of the nested while loop or is it O(n)?

```
void BST::displayEntries() {
    Node* currentNode = root;
    Node* prevNode;
    while (currentNode != nullptr) {
        if (isLeaf(currentNode->leftChild)) {
            std::cout << currentNode->key << " " << currentNode->item << std::endl;
            currentNode = currentNode->rightChild;
        }
        else {
            prevNode = currentNode->leftChild;
            while (!isLeaf(prevNode->rightChild) && prevNode->rightChild != currentNode) 
                prevNode = prevNode->rightChild;
            if (isLeaf(prevNode->rightChild)) {
                prevNode->rightChild = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode->leftChild;
            }
            else {
                prevNode->rightChild = nullptr;
                std::cout << currentNode->key << " " << currentNode->item << std::endl;
                currentNode = currentNode->rightChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm also very confused about recursive functions, does this public method inherit the time complexity due to the recursive function call?

```
BST::ItemType* BST::lookup(KeyType soughtKey)
{
    return lookupRec(soughtKey, root);
}
```

With the private recursive function defined as follows which I'm guessing is O(log n) but feel free to correct me, so would the public method (The previously shown non recursive container) also have a complexity of O(log n)?

```
BST::ItemType* BST::lookupRec(KeyType soughtKey, Node* currentNode) {
    if (isLeaf(currentNode))
    {
        return(nullptr);
    }
    if (soughtKey > currentNode->key) {
        lookupRec(soughtKey, currentNode->rightChild);
    }
    else if (soughtKey < currentNode->key) {
        lookupRec(soughtKey, currentNode->leftChild);
    }
    else {
        return(&currentNode->item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but in `lookupRec()` you should also `*return* lookupRec(...)`

Comment: We cannot answer only judging by this piece of code.
Its more a question whether you make some housekeeping to make your tree balanced.
RB Trees usually do some extra rotations to keep the balancing criteria.

Comment: I have not done any housekeeping to make the tree balanced.

Comment: Then for the worst case you need to consider a lopsided tree that goes all to one side and is basically a linked list with linear lookups. If you have no balancing then you will usually get this by inserting a sequence of values that is already sorted.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that `displayEntries` doesn't actually work properly unless the tree is really weirdly put together and the method is misnamed. Does it work (what does it do?)? If it doesn't, maybe you should fix it before trying to estimate its complexity.

Comment: The displayEntries function does work as intended, it performs an inorder traversal of the tree and displays each entry

Comment: First time I see a traversal that's altering the tree (`prevNode->rightChild = currentNode`) but you live and learn...